# arbitrary rewrite or redirect of an url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I Change Example 1 to Example 2 using mod_rewrite.

Example 1

```
http://localhost/a/posts/1/12/abcd
```

Example 2

```
http://localhost/a/members/1/posts/page.php?pid=12
```

Comment: Using .htaccess or httpd.conf?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule posts/(\d+)/(\d+)/.* members/$1/posts/page.php?pid=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^a/posts/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/.*$ a/members/$1/posts/page.php?pid=$2 [L]
```

^a/posts/ means your URI should start with /a/posts/
([0-9]+) is a numerical substring and should contain at least one digit
.*$ contains anything left to the end of URI
a/members/$1/posts/page.php?pid=$2 creates your result

In your case:

```
Requested URL: http://localhost/a/posts/1/12/abcd
URI: /a/posts/1/12/abcd
$1: 1
$2: 12
Request Result: http://localhost/a/members/1/posts/page.php?pid=12
```